# Пользовательская функция добавления в поля базы по ключам массива

Tags: php

Хочу написать функцию, которая добавляет в поля базы по ключам из определенного массива, которые идентичны некоторым в $_POST (мы заранее знаем, какие ключи придут). Это есть сейчас:

```
function insert($cmd, array $required) {
  $fields = implode(", ", $required);
  if ($result = mysqli_query($link, 'INSERT INTO '.$cmd.' ('.$fields.')
                                     VALUES ('$_POST[type]', '$_POST[status]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[user]', '$_POST[duration]', '$_POST[link]', '$_POST[token]', '$_POST[callid]')')) {

    /* Освобождаем используемую память */
    mysqli_free_result($result);

  } 
)
```

Интересует, как бы поправить блок после Values, да и как можно это сделать получше.

Использовать же функцию буду примерно так:

```
$required = array('type', 'status', 'phone', 'user', 'duration', 'link', 'crm_token', 'callid');
insert($_POST['cmd'], $required);
```

Comment: Используя подготовленные выражения конечно. Это единственный безопасный вариант.

Comment: Это как, например?

Comment: Это например почитать вот здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: После `INSERT` в `result` будет хранится `bool`, его не нужно освобождать.

Comment: Хм, спасибо) Подготовленные выражения - интересная тема. u_mulder, создайте тогда полноценный ответ, я проголосую.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем, если взять код из предыдущего ответа и поправить его

```
function insert(mysqli $link, string $table, array $required) 
{
    $fields     = "`".implode("`, `", $required)."`";
    $fields_num = count( $required );
    $questions  = str_repeat( "?,", $fields_num - 1 ) . "?";
    $query      = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields) VALUES ($questions)";

    $data = [];
    foreach( $required as $field ){ 
        $data[] = $_POST[$field];
    }

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query );

    //'s' для строковых данных, но вполне нормально работает со всеми параметрами.
    $types = str_repeat('s', $fields_num );
    $stmt->bind_param( $types, ...$data );
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Использовать так:

```
$required = array('type', 'status', 'phone', 'user', 'duration', 'link', 'crm_token', 'callid');
$table = "table";
insert($link, $table, $required);
```

Разумеется, имя таблицы ни из какого поста категорически брать нельзя. Да и не имеет ни малейшего смысла. Так что имя таблицы жестко прописываем у скрипте.

Comment: string убрал, чтобы в версии 5,6 работало перед `string $table` :)